# Under what conditions is $V \rtimes_f \mathbb{k}$ isomorphic to $W \rtimes_g \mathbb{k}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semidirect-product

Given a $\mathbb{k}$-vector space $V$ and an endomorphism $f$ of $V$, we can regard $V$ an an abelian Lie algebra and construct the semidirect product $V \rtimes_f \mathbb{k}$.
It is given by the vector space $V \oplus \mathbb{k}$ together with the Lie bracket
$$
  [ (v, \lambda) , (w, \mu) ]
  =
  ( \lambda f(w) - \mu f(v), 0 ) \,.
$$

> **Question.** Under what conditions is $V \rtimes_f \mathbb{k}$ isomorphic to $W \rtimes_g \mathbb{k}$?

The question is motivated from the following example:
Let $f(\tau)$ be the endomorphism of $\mathbb{k}^2$ given by the matrix
$$
  f(\tau)
  \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &      \\
      & \tau
  \end{pmatrix} \,.
$$
The resulting semidirect products $\mathfrak{g}_\tau := \mathbb{k}^2 \rtimes_{f(\tau)} \mathbb{k}$ with $\tau \in \mathbb{k}$ are a standard example for infinitely many non-isomorphic, three-dimensional Lie algebras:
the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_\tau$ and $\mathfrak{g}_\upsilon$ are isomorphic if and only if $\tau = \upsilon$ or $\tau \upsilon = 1$.

---

Let us abbreviate $V \rtimes_f \mathbb{k}$ as $\mathfrak{g}_f$.
So far, I’ve found out the following:

- Both $V$ and $W$ need to have the same dimension, so one may assume for simplicity that $W = V$.
- $\mathfrak{g}_f$ is abelian if and only if $f = 0$. This entails that $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is isomorphic to no other $\mathfrak{g}_f$.
- The center of $\mathfrak{g}_f$ is given by $\ker(f) \oplus 0$, and the derived Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{g}_f$ is given by $\operatorname{im}(f) \oplus 0$. We hence find that $f$ and $g$ need to have the same rank, the same nullity, and the same corank.
- Suppose that the two endomorphisms $f$ and $g$ of $V$ are similar, and let $\varphi$ be a vector space automorphism of $V$ with $g = \varphi f \varphi^{-1}$. We have an isomorphism of Lie algebras
  $$
    \mathfrak{g}_f
    \to
    \mathfrak{g}_g \,,
    \quad
    (v, \lambda)
    \mapsto
    (\varphi(v), \lambda) \,.
  $$
- For any nonzero scalar $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{k}$ we have an isomorphism of Lie algebras
  $$
    \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha f}
    \to
    \mathfrak{g}_f \,,
    \quad
    (v, \lambda)
    \mapsto
    (v, \alpha \lambda) \,.
  $$
- For every linear map $\beta$ from $\mathbb{k}$ to $V$ we have an automorphism of Lie algebras
  $$
    \mathfrak{g}_f
    \to
    \mathfrak{g}_f \,,
    \quad
    (v, \lambda)
    \mapsto
    (v + \beta(\lambda), \lambda) \,.
  $$

---

If $f$ is surjective, then the above observations suffice to answer the question:

It follows from the surjectivity of $f$  that $f$ has corank $0$, which means that $g$ has corank $0$, whence $g$ is surjective, too.
It follows that $[\mathfrak{g}_g, \mathfrak{g}_g]$ has codimension $1$ in $\mathfrak{g}_g$, which means that $g$ is also surjective.

Every isomorphism of Lie algebras $\theta$ from $\mathfrak{g}_f$ to $\mathfrak{g}_g$ must therefore map $V \oplus 0 = [\mathfrak{g}_f, \mathfrak{g}_f]$ to $V \oplus 0 = [\mathfrak{g}_g, \mathfrak{g}_g]$.
With respects to the decompositions of vector spaces $\mathfrak{g}_f = V \oplus \mathbb{k}$ and $\mathfrak{g}_g = V \oplus \mathbb{k}$ we can therefore express $\theta$ as an upper triangular matrix
$$
  \theta
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \varphi & \beta \\
    0       & \alpha
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\varphi$ is a vector space endomorphism of $V$, $\alpha$ is a scalar in $\mathbb{k}$ and $\beta$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{k}$ to $V$.
That $\theta$ is a homomophism of Lie algebras means that $\varphi f = \alpha g \varphi$, and the invertibility of $\theta$ is equivalent to the invertibility of both $\varphi$ and $\alpha$.
We hence find that $f$ is similar to $\alpha g$, which is a nonzero scalar multiple of $g$.

Together with the above observations this shows that if $f$ is surjective, then $\mathfrak{g}_f$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}_g$ if and only if $f$ is similar to a nonzero scalar multiple of $g$.

Comment: Aren't you classifying the Lie algebra extensions of $\mathbb k$ by the abelian Lie algebra $V$? Then is that a relatively straightforward special case of this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+algebra+extension and https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nonabelian+Lie+algebra+cohomology ? At least I see that a 2-cocycle here basically boils down to the choice of one $f\in Der(V)= End(V)$, and maybe if one unravels the condition for being cohomologous, one finds the differing by scalar multiple in the case you have, and exactly what you're looking for in other cases. Or I am totally off.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg An equivalence of extensions $\theta \colon \mathfrak{g}_f \to \mathfrak{g}_g$ would need to be the identity on $V$ as well as the identity mod $V$. This would mean that $\theta = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \beta \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. This only gives an isomorphism between $\mathfrak{g}_f$ and $\mathfrak{g}_f$ itself. This result makes sense: Every abelian extension $\mathfrak{e}$ of $\mathbb{k}$ by $V$ gives rise to a $\mathbb{k}$-module structure on $V$, and equivalent extensions give the same module. But $\mathfrak{g}_f$ and $\mathfrak{g}_g$ give the same module iff $f = g$.